# What is inside a General Purpose Operational Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I am trying to analyze the building blocks of an operational amplifier and for that purpose I have chosen, probably one of the most famous and earliest op-amps built, [ua741](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjOhZXW1q_UAhWIW7wKHc7RBtcQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Fua741.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH_5NcGA1Lw1ZmGXFOZGz2e7KqQqw).

I have figured out most of the building blocks, such as differential pairs, push-pulls, current sources, class AB op amps etc, however there are still some parts that I don't have any explains yet. One of which the highlighted line below for the class AB amp which I was expecting to be connected to `Vcc-`.

[image]

What is the function of the yellow line?

Comment: http://www.righto.com/2015/10/inside-ubiquitous-741-op-amp-circuits.html

Comment: Everything you need to know, right [here](http://shop.emscdn.com/KitInstrux/741/741_principles_RevA104.pdf)

Comment: Two fantastic, fantastic recommendations, however, if you have noticed already, the path that I have highlighted does not exist on any of the earlier 741 schematics and the path feeds back to the `Gain Stage` rather than the `Differential Amplifier` block, going in particular from `Q17` to `Q22` and not to `Q5` in **Figure 2: Detailed schematic diagram** of the @Micah 's recommendation. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PNP who's collector node you have highlighted - let's call it Q1  (as well as the NPN directly above it on the schematic) are for current limiting at the output. The output current develops a voltage over the two resistors connected to OUT - IOUT*RSENSE. When this voltage exceeds a diode voltage, Q1 starts to turn on. The positive and negative current limits work differently, but the negative current limit which you have asked about specifically operates by sending a current back to the input and reducing the differential current generated by the input pair!

Answer (score 1):

From its position monitoring current from the -VDD rail, the effect will be current limiting or perhaps foldback limiting to restrict power dissipation.